# Strongly typed Settings class in a services library getting settings from web.config in mvc project

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a solution with multiple projects. One of them is a Services project and within that most of my backend code resides and thus, the settings for most of those services reside in its app.config file.

I created a class to access all those settings, so they would be available outside the Services project.

```
public static class ServicesAppSettings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple App Settings classes for strong typing
    /// When creating a new class please ENSURE THAT THE PROPERTY NAME EXACTLY MATCHES THE APPSETTINGS KEY!
    /// </summary>

    public static class SmsSettings
    {
        public static string SmsProvider => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsProvider"];
        public static string SmsAccountId => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsAccountId"];
        public static string SmsPassword => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsAccountPassword"];
        public static string SmsFromPhone => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsFromPhone"];
    }

    public static class EmailSettings
    {
        public static string EmailProvider => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailProvider"];
        public static string EmailProviderHost => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailProviderHost"];
        public static string EmailAccount => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAccount"];
        public static string EmailAccountPassword => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAccountPassword"];

        public static string GetEmailAddressFromApplication()
        {
            return string.Format(EmailAccount + "@" + EmailProvider);
        }
    }

    public static class UserIcons
    {
        public static string MaleUserIconSource => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaleUserIcon"];
        public static string FemaleUserIconSource => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FemaleUserIcon"];
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly fine EXCEPT when the settings aren't in the WEB.CONFIG file. Why on earth is this drawing from the mvc's web.config file and NOT its own libraries app.config file. Trust me, this is the case. If I remove one setting from web.config and then try to access it in a test it's null, if i put it back in web.config it works.

Anyone know why this is? Can you specify to the ConfigurationManager the name of the file you want to retrieve from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because only one configuration file is actually accessible - config of your executable project. That's why in mvc application you can read settings from `web.config` of your executable mvc application. If you would have service application (ms service) it will be `app.config` of you startup service.

As I know, you can not read settings from another config file.

One the possible solutions is to store your custom settings in `.xml` file and read it. This is also useful if you want to change your custom settings at a runtime.

Another one (in case you don't want to mess up your settings in `appSettings` section) is to create your custom config section and use it for your settings

Hope that helps

Comment: Aren't the settings from app.config compiled into the libraries dll? If only the web.config matters even with 7 other projects in the solution why would any of those other class libraries ever need an app.config?

Comment: As I know, it deneds on build type/build action of config files.

Answer (score 0):

Web.config is the place to put your settings. Dlls that are part of a .net web solution will use it.